# Deleting duplicate words from different text files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to delete same words comparing two different files.

file_list.txt and name.txt are files.

What I want to do is to compare two files and delete a word in file_list.txt

if the same word is in name.txt

For instance,
the file_list.txt has lines below

```
D:\working\Python
D:\working\perl
D:\working\java
D:\working\C++
```

and name.txt has lines below

```
Python
perl
```

then the result should be like this.

```
D:\working\
D:\working\
D:\working\java
D:\working\C++
```

or that also would be a good way if lines would be deleted so only third and fourth lines remains like this.

```
D:\working\java
D:\working\C++
```

I tried to find a solution here in this site but this code is working only when
matching a line, not a word.

```
import fileinput
with open('file_list.txt') as fin:
    exclude = set(line.rstrip() for line in fin)

for line in fileinput.input('name.txt', inplace=True):
    if line.rstrip() not in exclude:
        print line,
```

Comment: You could for example split your paths to their components, form a set of said components, and check if that set intersects with the exclude set.

Comment: Do you have file_list.txt and name.txt mixed up? You'll overwrite name.txt with your current example.

Comment: Ilja Everilä, my mistake. I currently edit file names. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a set of words to exclude, you could for example form a set of parts of the paths and check if they [intersect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
from pathlib import Path

with open('name.txt') as fin:
    exclude = set(line.rstrip() for line in fin)

with fileinput.input('file_list.txt', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not exclude.intersection(Path(line.rstrip()).parts):
            print(line, end='')
```

This is a Python 3 answer, since you've included the relevant tag. To use pathlib in Python 2, you could use the [pathlib2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/) backports package. Alternatively you could split using [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep):

```
import os

...

with fileinput.input('file_list.txt', inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not exclude.intersection(line.rstrip().split(os.sep)):
            print(line, end='')
```

Note that this will only remove exact matches, not for example:

```
D:\working\CPython
```

given

```
Python
perl
```

If you need a more generic substring match, consult the other answers that use string [membership tests](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used code you answered, but im afraid it's not working. im sorry that im not familier with 'intersection' method

Comment: could you please give another tip or method please?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would switch the the order, and create a bag of words that are "bad words". Then, I'd check, for each of my lines, if it contains a bad word.

This is my suggested modification to your code:

```
with open('name.txt') as names:
    bad_words = set(name.rstrip() for name in names)

with open('file_list.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            print(line)
```

Comment: results = []
with open('file_list.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            results.append(line)

at the end your can either write the results back into new file etc etc.

Comment: @AsadIqbal I agree with your logic, but I tried to make this a simple fix with similar logic to the original answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if line.rstrip() not in exclude` is testing whether the entire line is in the list of excluded words.

A simple fix would be to replace this with `if any(word in line for word in exclude)`

If you are guaranteed to have the same format for all lines as in the list you provided, then you could extract the text after the final `\` and check if it is in your excluded list, which will be more efficient:

```
if '\' in line and line.split('\')[-1].strip() in exclude:
    ...
```